# calculating power and los follow-up in a study

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, statistical-power, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I have questions about this paper [1](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(21)01431-8/fulltext)

- what is the power of this study?
- what does it mean if lost follow-up more than 20%?
- why the Kaplan-Meier curve was used beside the cox?

Many thnx

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an entire paragraph in the [cited paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(21)01431-8), on page 1420, on the power analysis performed prior to the study. It ends with:

> For the primary analysis for the chest signs subgroup, we estimated we would need 119 cases (for $\alpha$ 0·05, 80% power) assuming 40% of the trial cohort had chest signs (based on study data at the time when calculations were revised), or a total trial sample of 298 for 80% power and 398 for 90% power. For other subgroups, we estimated we needed 225 cases for 90% power and an α of 0·01.

2. The results of the paper are based on the participants who continued through follow up. The results are what they are, based on that actual study size. The loss to follow up was about 26% (115 out of 432 participants examined at baseline), leaving 317 with follow up. A 20% loss was anticipated (see the paragraph not above about power in the paper), which would have left 346 with follow up. So they still had 92% (317/346) of the numbers they might have expected.
3. Kaplan-Meier curves (Figure 2 of the paper) are a convenient way to represent time-to-event data when there are only a few groups. They have the advantage of showing something close to the raw data. In this case, the symptom duration for placebo and antibiotic groups overlapped substantially in that plot. Kaplan-Meier curves have the disadvantage of not readily taking into account multiple covariates. The Cox analysis in the paper showed that there was not a significant difference between the placebo and antibiotic groups in terms of symptom duration even after adjusting for other covariates.